# Java getting the auto-increment number of the current inserted row, to use it for another query?

Tags: java, mysql

```
public static void updateHistory(Client winner) {
    try {
        if (winner != null) {
            getDatabase().newQuery("INSERT INTO tournaments (`players`, `winner`, `winnerKills`, `map`, `prize`) VALUES ('" + tournyPlayers.size() +"', '" + winner.playerName + "', '" + winner.killCount + "', 'Wilderness', '" + winner.gameScore + "')");
        }
        else {
            getDatabase().newQuery("INSERT INTO tournaments (`players`, `winner`, `winnerKills`, `map`, `prize`) VALUES ('" + tournyPlayers.size() +"', 'None', 'None', 'Wilderness', 'None')");            
        }

        ArrayList<Client> player = tournyPlayers;

        for (int i = 0; i < player.size(); i++) {
            if (player.get(i).killedByPlayer == "") {
                getDatabase().newQuery("INSERT INTO tournament_players (`name`, `kills`, `killedBy`, `score`, `points`) VALUES ('" + player.get(i).playerName + "', '" + player.get(i).killCount + "', 'N/A', '" + player.get(i).gameScore + "', '" + player.get(i).gamePoints + "')");
            }
            else {
                getDatabase().newQuery("INSERT INTO tournament_players (`name`, `kills`, `killedBy`, `score`, `points`) VALUES ('" + player.get(i).playerName + "', '" + player.get(i).killCount + "', '" + player.get(i).killedByPlayer + "', '" + player.get(i).gameScore + "', '" + player.get(i).gamePoints + "')");                
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Well what I am trying to do is, insert a new tournament row, which will display the information about the tournament, now I want to add the players to the tournament (Who was playing it), so I now will add each player, into a new row, with his data.

But now I want to make sure that the player matches the current tournament I inserted. I can't make a unique number of the current server, server-sided because the server may go down, and lose the count.

therefore I've thought of using the inserted tournaments table's auto_increment ID, and add it along with the inserted player, so his id will be tournament's auto increment id.

Is there a way to fetch the auto increment ID without using the exact same data I inserted into the tournaments (cause there may be 2 tournaments with the same status, who knows).

***Is there a way to do so?***

*I was thinking of adding a MD5 hash with the date + time, to the tournaments row and then add it to the player's row, is that a good solution?*

Comment: `so his id will be tournament's auto increment id` No, the player id should be unique too. Consider having a foreign key column that associates the player with a tournament or better have a player_tournament association table if a player can take part in multiple tournaments.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `Statement#getGeneratedKeys()` which returns a `ResultSet` that you can use to retrieve any generated *primary keys* as

```
ResultSet rsKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rsKeys.next()) {
    tournament.setId(rsKeys.getLong(1));
}
```

Please, note that you need to give a hint to the JDBC driver that you would like to retrieve the generated keys while preparing a `PreparedStatement` as

```
connection.prepareStatement(strSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

or, at the time of executing a `Statement` as

```
statement.executeUpdate(strSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

***Reference:***
[Statement#getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29)

> Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result of executing this Statement object. If this Statement object did not generate any keys, an empty ResultSet object is returned.