# h2 getGeneratedKeys throws exception

Tags: java, sql, h2

I try to put some Data in my H2 database but I'm a total noob in databases so it throws error over error since more than a hour.
Normaly I can fix it somehow but now I got a new problem I try to use 
getGeneratedKeys() first I tried to use AUTO_INCREMENT(1,1) but that didn't works too function but it won't work rigth.

The exception my programm throws is

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Funktion "GETGENERATEDKEYS" nicht gefunden
>   Function "GETGENERATEDKEYS" not found; SQL statement:
>   insert into logTbl values( getGeneratedKeys(),Webservice->startThread0: Thread0) [90022-173]

an my database function looks like this

```
    public void createTable(String Log) {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("TREIBER FEHLER");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/DBtest/Logs");

        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();


        stat.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logTbl(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, LOG VARCHAR(255))");

        //stat.execute("insert into test values(1, 'Hello')");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            stat.execute("insert into logTbl values( getGeneratedKeys()," + Log + ")");
        }
            stat.close();
            conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SQL FEHLER");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

hope you can help me to fix my error as I said I'm totaly new and just had some code example as "tutorial" because I don't found a good tutorial

Comment: `getGeneratedKeys()` is a Java method of the `PreparedStatement` class, it's **not** a SQL function, so you can't use it inside a SQL statement. [See the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) and the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/statement.html#1000569) for details

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25214466/330315) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18337542/330315)

Comment: ahh nice Thank u :D I'll try to understand but it's not that easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to automatically generate primary key values, you need to first change the definition of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logTbl
(
  ID integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  LOG VARCHAR(255)
);
```

You should also use a `PreparedStatement` rather than concatenating values.

So your Java code would look something like this:

```
String insert = "insert into logTbl (log) values(?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insert,  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
long id = -1;
while (rs.next()) 
{
   rs.getLong(1);
}
```

It might be that you need to use the overloaded version of `prepareStatement()` where you supply the column to be returned. Not sure which one works with H2:

```
prepareStatement(insert, new String[] {"ID"});
```

---

Btw: there is nothing "magic" about 255 as the length of a varchar column. There is no performance difference between `varchar(500)`, varchar(20)`or varchar(255)`. You should use the length that you expect you need, not some "magic" limit you think performs better.

Comment: Nice thank you :D nearly works I think the last work I can do by myself hehe :D .
Ahh oke didn't knew that thougth the 255 is some kinde of maximum in databases haha :D but i work with logs from log4j so I think 100 will suit.